# Complexe SQL query and pagination

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have these tables

```
                         clients
                         ----------
                         -id 
                         -full_name 

 payments                invoices
 -------------           ----------
 -id                     -id  
 -payable_id             -client_id 
 -payable_type           
                         credits
                         ----------
                         -id  
                         -client_id
```

backed by these models:

#### payment model:

```
belongs_to :payable, polymorphic: true
```

#### client model

```
has_many :invoices
has_many :credits
has_many :payments, as: :payable
```

#### invoice/credit models

```
belongs_to :client
has_many :payments, as: :payable
```

A `client` can have many `payments`:

- direct payments
- payment to the the client documents(invoices/credits)

My question is how to fetch a client payments(*direct* AND *via documents*) in an `active_relation` object, so I can paginate the results?

Comment: How about reworking the database structure to have both client_id and invoice_id (can be null for direct payments) on the payment and get rid of polymorphic association? It would get really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wouldn't want to take advice of what I suggested in my comment under the question, you might go with writing your own SQL for precise retrieval of required records:

```
class Payment
  def self.of_client(client)
    where(<<-SQL
            (payable_type = 'client' AND payable_id = ?) OR
            (payable_type = 'invoice' AND payable_id IN
              (SELECT id FROM invoices WHERE client_id = ?))
          SQL, client.id, client.id)
  end
end
```